# Texture to Mesh Directly?

Tags: mesh, texturing, sculpting, texture-painting

I see that it is possible to sculpt a mesh using a texture, but is it possible to sculpt automatically a mesh with its own texture? Specifically, let's say you have a mesh representing a character. The mesh is really simple, and the texture is simple enough details. Is it possible to sculpt easly these details on the mesh? The reason I'm asking this is that I want to make rocks, but I have to sculpt on the mesh above the texture manually. It makes the process of painting easier once made, but the whole thing is time-consuming. Thank you very much! The textures and masks are listed here below.

[image: base texture] [image: Mask one] [image: Mask two]

Comment: Narrow it down a little.   Is this question about making brushes?  Making rocks?  Or adding more textural detail to a character?

Comment: This is about making rocks. Is there something into which I can input the texture to directly affect the mesh of an object?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to texture paint and sculpt at the same time, If this is what you mean by “texture directly to mesh”.  As I understand your question it would be a way of combining workspaces.
There are workarounds:

Custom displacement maps

Custom brushes

Additive:
Here is one from the popular Blender secrets tutorial:

1. Use the multi resolution and mask modifiers on an object
2. Create a drawing On the surface of the object and invert the mask
3. Raise the non-masked areas using the inflate and smooth sculpt tools

Subtractive:

1.Create a texture map from an image

2.Use a displace modifier and apply it to the mesh

3.”Erase” detail from the map using the various sculpt tools

I still think that in terms of rocks, In preferences enabling the extra objects and then pressing F3 for search and typing in “rock generator” gets you closest to a tool that has multiple options.  You can texture your randomized rocks with your own displacement maps and get some pretty wide results.
You can also apply various modifiers to get different results that you can sculpt as much as you wish.